# SVG converted to GIF is only one frame

Tags: animation, svg, animated-gif, file-conversion

I have this .svg file:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="L7" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px"
        y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve">
        <path fill="#111" d="M31.6,3.5C5.9,13.6-6.6,42.7,3.5,68.4c10.1,25.7,39.2,38.3,64.9,28.1l-3.1-7.9c-21.3,8.4-45.4-2-53.8-23.3
c-8.4-21.3,2-45.4,23.3-53.8L31.6,3.5z">
            <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" dur="2s" from="0 50 50"
                to="360 50 50" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        </path>
        <path fill="#111" d="M42.3,39.6c5.7-4.3,13.9-3.1,18.1,2.7c4.3,5.7,3.1,13.9-2.7,18.1l4.1,5.5c8.8-6.5,10.6-19,4.1-27.7
        c-6.5-8.8-19-10.6-27.7-4.1L42.3,39.6z">
            <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" dur="1s" from="0 50 50"
                to="-360 50 50" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        </path>
        <path fill="#111" d="M82,35.7C74.1,18,53.4,10.1,35.7,18S10.1,46.6,18,64.3l7.6-3.4c-6-13.5,0-29.3,13.5-35.3s29.3,0,35.3,13.5
    L82,35.7z">
            <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" dur="2s" from="0 50 50"
                to="360 50 50" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        </path>
    </svg>
```

I want to convert it to a .gif, though whatever converter I choose, I get a .gif file with only one frame. I have tried [zamzar.com](https://www.zamzar.com/), all services from [this article](https://blog.media.io/gif/svg-to-gif.html) and maybe some other websites, so I think the problem should be somewhere in the code.

What can cause this?

Comment: presumably the .gif converter does not support SMIL.